# How to surround elements in a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html string which looks like:

```
var form = '<form data-hint="blah">' +
                    '<label for=\"password0\">Password0</label>' +
                    '<input type=\"password\" name=\"password0\" id=\"password0\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 0\" />' +
                    '<label for=\"password1\">Password 1</label>' +
                    '<input type=\"password\" name=\"password1\" id=\"password1\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 2\" />' +
                    '</form>';
```

I want to seach the string (with Jquery, but open to alternatives) for inputs with `data-hint` attribute. I then want to surround the found inputs and their accompanying labels in a div container. So for example, the string above when printed out should lok like:

```
   <form data-hint="blah"> 
    <div>
       <label for=\"password0\">Password0</label> 
       <input type=\"password\" name=\"password0\" id=\"password0\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 0\" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
       <label for=\"password1\">Password 1</label> +
       <input type=\"password\" name=\"password1\" id=\"password1\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 2\" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's my code:

```
$(form).find('input[data-hint]').each(function() {

    id = $(this).attr('id');

    //put <div> before the label
    form = $(self.form).find('label[for=' + id + ']').before('<div>').parents('form')[0].outerHTML;

    //put the closing div after the input
    form = $(self.form).find('input#' + id).after('</div>').parents('form')[0].outerHTML;
});
```

But I end up with Jquery inserting `<div></div>` before the `label` and after the `input`...

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfg2hn4c/1/)

Comment: Just replace "self.form" with just "form". That will eliminate errors

Comment: Have you tried using jquery .wrap() and .wrapInner()?

Comment: Why is `form` a string at all, and not an element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfg2hn4c/2/):

```
var form = '<form data-hint="blah">' +
        '<label for=\"password0\">Password0</label>' +
        '<input type=\"password\" name=\"password0\" id=\"password0\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 0\" />' +
        '<label for=\"password1\">Password 1</label>' +
        '<input type=\"password\" name=\"password1\" id=\"password1\" data-hint=\"Please enter your Password 2\" />' +
        '</form>';

var id, self = this;
var $form = $(form);
$form.hide().appendTo(document.body)
$form.find('input[data-hint]').each(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $form.find("label[for="+id+"]").wrap("<div></div>");

}).html();

console.log($form.get(0).outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .before('<div>') … .after('</div>')
> ```

That's not how jQuery works. It does not manipulate the html markup, but the DOM - you cannot just insert markup snippets into it. Instead, you will need to create a new element, put it in place of the input and then move the input and label into it:

```
$(form).find('input[data-hint]').each(function() {
    var div = $("<div>").insertBefore(this);
    div.append(this.labels).append(this);
});
```

([updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfg2hn4c/3/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

```
$('[data-hint]').each(function() {
    $(this).prev('label').addBack().wrap('<div>');
});
```

This will run through each element that has a data-hint attribute, while iterating them, it will add the accompanying label to the stack of selected elements, and wrap them both with a div. You can add attributes to that div to change it to your liking.

Comment: Excellent! Removing Comments.